# Individual video watermark for user

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark

Need to set individual watermark for each user while he downloads video. 
Watermark should be placed for 3-5 seconds in the same place and starts from N second of video. How I can do it without full video reconvert and as fast as it can be.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in the matter by any means, but if the user is actually downloading the video, I'm pretty sure it would require for the video to be rendered with the watermark. If the user is streaming the video onto a webpage, then perhaps you could add a layer onto the page using some sort of transparency.

Comment: Watermark must be in downloaded video file to detect user who can publish video outside the service.

Comment: sounds like you almost want to have some digital rights management.

Comment: A watermark is only a visual indicator. It may prevent people some from using it just because they don't want the visual overlay. If you want true DRM-really prevent people from using something outside of specified means, then you need real DRM.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread. [Xvid provides a watermarking service for video content distribution.](https://autograph.xvid.com/) Their implementation adds an invisible watermark that's unique to each user of your content. It works with Steganography.

Maybe this would help others out there. It makes content traceable back to the source of the leak. I.e. the user who first leaked the content.